# Imagebutton in TableLayout too big

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, layout, imageview

I have a Scrollview and inside of it a Tablelayout. The Tablelayout is defined in xml like this:

```
<TableLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/tablelayout"/>
```

The rows for the tablelayout and their views are added programatically like this:

```
private void createFeedLayout(int menuId, int newestOrBest, int count, int startId) {

TableLayout tbl = (TableLayout)FindViewById(Resource.Id.tablelayout);
List<Helpers.Objects.Picture> pictures = getPictures(menuId, newestOrBest, startId, count);
TableRow row = new TableRow(this);

tbl.AddView(row);
row.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.background_whitebar_challengeopen);

foreach (Helpers.Objects.Picture picture in pictures)
{
    if (counter == PICTURESINAROW) 
    {
        row = new TableRow(this);
        row.SetGravity(GravityFlags.Left);
        row.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.background_whitebar_challengeopen);
        tbl.AddView(row);
        counter = 0;
    }

    Bitmap bmp_picture = PhotoHelpers.DecodePhotoFromBase64(picture.photo);
    bmp_picture = PhotoHelpers.ResizeImage(bmp_picture, (Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / PICTURESINAROW) - SPACEBETWEENPICS, 
                                                       (Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels / PICTURESINAROW) - SPACEBETWEENPICS, false); 

    ImageButton button = new ImageButton(this);
    button.Id = i;
    button.Click += openImage;
    button.SetImageBitmap(bmp_picture);
    button.SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red);
    button.SetAdjustViewBounds(true);

    row.AddView(button);
    counter++;
    i++;
    }
}
```

}

The code adds 3 pictures in a Tablerow and then creates a new row. The expected results would be 3 pictures that are positioned directly next to each other, starting at the left edge of the screen.

But instead I get something like this:

(Only the part with red background matters)

[image: Result image]

And here I´m confused. I added `SetAdjustViewBounds(true);` to each button, and thought that this would cause the button to be just as big as the picture. Therefore the `SetBackgroundColor(Color.Red);` shouldn´t matter at all. But it seems like the button is having a big frame around it.

Has someone an idea what could cause this behaviour?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Use button.Background method instead of button.SetImageBitmap(bmp_picture) method ： button.Background = new BitmapDrawable(Resources, bmp_picture);

Comment: Hi. I tried this, but now the picture only gets streched. So it is not square any more. For me it seems like the Tablelayout has something like a static width for each column in a tablerow, and therefore the button is streched to meet the requirements. Is that possible?

Comment: The width for each column in a tablerow decided by yourself,  the bitmap's width.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I got it to work. the problem was the TableLayout itself. The round pictures in the middle of the screen, were also part of that layout. The TableRows in the "red" area somehow adapted the column width of these previous TableRows.

Therefore I created a new TableLayout and added the TableRows for the pictures on the bottom to it.

I´m sure there is a better solution, but at least it works now.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your image button to wrap the content, you need to set the LayoutParameters. try this:

```
button.LayoutParameters = new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I already tried it but it didn´t change anything. The confusing thing is. If I get the width of the button via `button.LayoutParameters.Width`, the size seems to be correct. But there ist still the red border around it...